# Multiple YACC grammars in one program

Tags: yacc

How do I compile, link and call different YACC grammars using `yyparse()` in one program?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the -p option for each separate yacc grammar *generation*

```
 -p prefix

           Use prefix instead of yy as the prefix for all external
           names produced by yacc.  For X/Open compliance, when the
           environment variable _XPG is set, then the -p option will work
           as described in the previous sentence.  If the environment
           variable _XPG is not set, then the -p option will work as
           described below in the -P option.
```